Reduction from np hard to np complete
I have couple of confusions regarding reduction:
(1) If A is NPC and B is NPC then reduction from A to B and B to A  possible.
(2) And if A is NPC and B is not known to be NPC, then reduction from A to B is possible.
(3) If A is not known be NPC and B is NPC then reduction from A to B isn't possible.
Am I correct of the above? I  mean reduction here polynomial time reduction.

Here are the key definitions.

$A$ is NP-hard if and only if $B\le_p A$ for every $B$ in NP. ($B\le_p A$ is pronounced "$B$ (polytime) reduces to $A$". Or, in your phrasing, "reduction from $B$ to $A$ is possible".)
A is NP-complete if and only if A is NP-hard and $A$ is in NP.

So (1) is correct.
If we know $A$ is NP-complete and we don't know anything about $B$, then we can't conclude anything about reducibilities between $A$ and $B$.
If we know $A$ is NP-complete and we know $B$ is in NP (but not necessarily that it is NP-complete), then we can conclude $B\le_p A$ but can't conclude that $A\le_p B.$
In general, if $A$ is NP-complete, we have $A\le_p B$ if and only if $B$ is NP-hard. (This is easy to prove using the definition above and the fact that $\le_p$ is transitive.)

I got it my question 1,2. But You are not tell anything about point 3?

I told you all about the case where one of the two is known to be NP-complete and the other is not. The only difference between the premises of 2 and 3 are that you switched the labels A and B.

Okay, understand. One question I have remained in my mind, we know that graph isomorphism isn't to be NPC, and also SAT is well known NPC, but I have found one reduction where SAT reduces to Graph isomorphism. See here. I don't how it makes sense.

@Beduin that’s a reduction of GI to SAT. Not a reduction of SAT to GI.

Ok, it's reduction of GI to SAT.  So, how does it make sense? Since we don't know about GI.

(Also, strictly speaking, we don’t know GI isn’t NPC. It is just strongly suspected since it's been proved that a) it is quasi-polynomial time  and b) if it were NP complete this would collapse the polynomial time hierarchy to level 2.)

We know GI is NP, and that’s enough to conclude it reduces to SAT, since SAT is NPC.

You last comment make sense, but GI isn’t NPC see here, I asked this question regarding this

@Beduin All that is claimed in the answer is that it is not known that GI is NPC and that it is unlikely that it is. What I am claiming is that we do not have a proof that GI is not NPC. And indeed, how could we? We famously don't have a proof that $P\ne NP$, and in the (unlikely) case that $P=NP$, GI (and every other problem in NP) would be NP-complete.

You have cleared lot of confusions in your one answer. Many thanks.

@Beduin No problem. (And just to make sure we're not oversimplifying, accord to what's currently known, if we had a proof $P\ne NP$, we couldn't necessarily conclude GI is not NP-complete either. However proofs of some widely-believed conjectures stronger than $P\ne NP$ (such as the exponential time hypothesis and $PH\ne \Pi_2^p$) would imply GI is not NP-complete.)
